# ListPointPlot3D + Grid

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have to plot some points in the 3d space. This is the code I use

```
data = {{1.5403, 0.583853, 0.0100075, 0.346356, 1.28366}, {2.5403, 1.58385, 
  1.01001, 1.34636, 2.28366}, {3.5403, 2.58385, 2.01001, 2.34636, 
  3.28366}, {4.5403, 3.58385, 3.01001, 3.34636, 4.28366}, {5.5403, 
  4.58385, 4.01001, 4.34636, 5.28366}}

PLOT = ListPointPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Thickness[0.0025]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Web", Axes -> True,
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.025]]
```

[image]

but I need to add a kind of grid that connects the points,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PLOT = ListPointPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Axes -> True,
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.025]];

lp3d = ListPlot3D[Join @@ MapIndexed[Append[Reverse@#2, #] &, data, {2}], 
   MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &}, 
   Mesh -> (Range /@ Dimensions[data]), 
   PlotStyle -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> Dashed,
   BoundaryStyle -> Dashed];

Show[PLOT, lp3d, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]